# If $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$, what are the eigenvalues of $(I - A)^{3}$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric real matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$, what are the eigenvalues of $(I - A)^{3}$?

Are they $(1 - \lambda_1)^3, (1 - \lambda_2)^3, \ldots, (1 - \lambda_n)^3$? If so, how can I arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: $(I-A)^3x_1=(I-A)^2(I-A)x_1=(I-A)^2x_1-(I-A)^2Ax_1=(1-\lambda_1)(I-A)^2x_1=\dots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Ax= \lambda x$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
(I-A)x &=& (1-\lambda)x \\ 
(I-A)^3 x &=& (1-\lambda)^3 x. \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: . . . n I c e !

Answer (score 1):

$\det(I-A-\mu I)=\det((1-\mu)I-A)\Rightarrow$ The eigenvalues $\mu_i$ of $I-A$ are the ones of the form $\mu_i=1-\lambda_i$ with $\lambda_i=1-\mu_i$ being an eigenvalue of $A$.

Now rename $B=I-A$ and consider $B^3$. Take $\mu_i$ an eigenvalue of $B$ and $v_i$ some eigenvector for $\mu_i$. If you consider $\mu^3$ then $B^3v_i=BBBv_i=BB\mu v_i=\mu BBv_i=\mu B\mu v_i=\mu^2B v_i=\mu^3v_i$, so $v_i$ is an eigenvector for $B^3$ with $\mu^3$ as eigenvalue.

We conclude the eigenvalues of $(I-A)^3$ are $(1-\lambda_1)^3,\ldots,(1-\lambda_n)^3$.